# go to the previous local html in UIWebView in iOS

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

In my project there are plenty of html files which through anchor links are connected to each other.
All of the html files are shown after selected in a `UITableView`, by an UIWebView. Once loaded the anchor links work and user can go to the chosen html.
Now the problem arises when want to go back, since whatever i do the back button in the navigation bar takes us to the `tableView` not the previous html.
How can i add a back button and how do i know that at any given time which html is being seen through `UIWebView` ?

```
import UIKit

class DisplayViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {


var articleName = “”
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    functionOfWebView()


}


func functionOfWebView()
{

    let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(articleName)", withExtension: "html")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL)
    webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by linking the webView's "goBack" action to a `UIButton`.

*I assume that you are navigating between the html files in the same webView.*

- From the storyboard, select the webView and then select "Connections Inspector":

[image]

- Note that there is "goBack" option in the list of "Received Actions"; Drag from its circle to a button:

[image]

Now, instead of popping the current ViewController, the button should do the desired functionality to your case (back to the previous webpage in the webview).

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot, although it doesn't goes back to the previous viewController but i figured that out. But how do i know which html is being shown now, to change the title for example ?

Comment: Glad to help. Well, it shouldn't let you back to a previous viewController, it represents the "back" button in a regular browser. You can get the current URL of the loaded page of the webView by: (webView.request?.URL.absoluteString)!

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, you should accept it (checkmark) :) It helps by telling the viewers it's a right answer for this case and it gives the answerer 15 extra points for reputation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i did a VC's property `isInitialWebPageLoaded` which reflects whether or not webView is loaded from HTML string or not - which implicates that user did tap link or something else happened.

To get know when it happened VC need to conform to `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and implement `func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool` like that:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    isInitialWebPageLoaded = navigationType != .linkClicked
    return true
}
```

After that with every back button action is being invoked i simply check:

```
if webView.canGoBack {
    webView.goBack()
} else if isInitialWebPageLoaded == false {
    webView.loadHTMLString(yourHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
} else {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You must to add an unique ID in the HTML and later when go back with "goBack" action parse the html finding the ID .